# Implementing Push notification with React Ui, Node Server and Python API

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, reactjs, push-notification, observable

I am new to the Javascript world, need to design a system where React Ui is calling a Node Server Rest API, which internally trigger Python Rest API, which is a hosting a long running (min 5 minutes) optimization model. We don't intend to make a blocking call instead wanted to notify the React Ui using Push notification (Observable Pattern). Something similar to Stack over flow page, where it provides an information that how many new questions are posted or a new answer or new comment is posted, which can then be refreshed and reviewed.

Sifting through the RxJs and Socket IO what I understood is, we can do the following:

1. Make an Async call using Observable, on the server Socket IO is used to subscribe and notify the client, which will do the communication between Node server and the React Client and follow a similar Push notification system at the Python server level, which notifies the Node server. Node server also executes a DB operation once the optimization job is complete
2. Another option is implementing the Queuing service between Node and python, which provides more durability and resilience to process the data using Pub - Sub model

Though our overall requirements are not enterprise oriented, we have low concurrency and resilience is not a critical factor, can some verify and let me know whether the above mentioned design options correct consideration or there are simpler options, which can help us meet our push notification use case